# how to use react-native flow types

Tags: javascript, react-native, flowtype

i just started using flow in a react native project. it looks like there are lots of nice flow typing already inlined for most react native apis. but how do i get my flow typechecker to use them in my project?

Here's an example that isn't working:

```
// @flow
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';

const fn = () => {
  StatusBar.setBarStyle('this-is-not-in-enum');
};
```

The call to StatusBar.setBarStyle should generate a flow error based on the flow types in the react-native source code. You can see that code in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.42-stable/Libraries/Components/StatusBar/StatusBar.js#L201

My .flowconfig:

```
[ignore]
; We fork some components by platform
.*/*[.]android.js

; Ignore templates for 'react-native init'
.*/local-cli/templates/.*

; Ignore the website subdir
<PROJECT_ROOT>/website/.*

; Ignore "BUCK" generated dirs
<PROJECT_ROOT>/\.buckd/

; Ignore unexpected extra "@providesModule"
.*/node_modules/.*/node_modules/fbjs/.*

; Ignore duplicate module providers
; For RN Apps installed via npm, "Libraries" folder is inside
; "node_modules/react-native" but in the source repo it is in the root
.*/Libraries/react-native/React.js
.*/Libraries/react-native/ReactNative.js

[include]

[libs]
Libraries/react-native/react-native-interface.js
flow/

[options]
emoji=true

module.system=haste

experimental.strict_type_args=true

munge_underscores=true

module.name_mapper='^[./a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\.\(bmp\|gif\|jpg\|jpeg\|png\|psd\|svg\|webp\|m4v\|mov\|mp4\|mpeg\|mpg\|webm\|aac\|aiff\|caf\|m4a\|mp3\|wav\|html\|pdf\)$' -> 'RelativeImageStub'

suppress_type=$FlowIssue
suppress_type=$FlowFixMe
suppress_type=$FixMe

suppress_comment=\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowFixMe\\($\\|[^(]\\|(\\(>=0\\.\\(3[0-8]\\|[1-2][0-9]\\|[0-9]\\).[0-9]\\)? *\\(site=[a-z,_]*react_native_oss[a-z,_]*\\)?)\\)
suppress_comment=\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowIssue\\((\\(>=0\\.\\(3[0-8]\\|1[0-9]\\|[1-2][0-9]\\).[0-9]\\)? *\\(site=[a-z,_]*react_native_oss[a-z,_]*\\)?)\\)?:? #[0-9]+
suppress_comment=\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowFixedInNextDeploy

unsafe.enable_getters_and_setters=true

[version]
^0.38.0
```

Comment: Did you actually run Flow? Flow does not run itself when you compile your React Native app, it is an external tool which must be ran in order to see type errors (Sorry if this seems like a stupid question, but it's good to check for trivial errors at first).

Comment: yes. it reports no errors. im guessing it is not working because of how react-native library source is setup.

Comment: I'm not sure on this and I can't test right now so I won't actually answer, but I think you might have to import the statusBarStyle type from React Native and explicitly state you want your string to belong to that enum (by doing var string: statusBarStyle) in order for this to be typechecked, but this is mostly just a guess.

Comment: good call. thats what i was thinking too. but that solution would not be as ideal as having flow just be able to "see" the inline types on the method setBarStyle

Comment: this PR is supposed to fix the current problem: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/12917

Comment: Is there any solution to this? I am getting no-undef error for all the flow type variables. My .flowconfig is similar to the one defined in this post.